# Filling cells with conditional column means

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'VAR_1' : [1,1,1,3,3], 
    'GROUP': [1,1,1,2,2],
})
```

My goal ist to create a seperate column "GROUP_MEAN" which holds the column "VAR_1" arithmetic mean value.

But - it should always consider the row value in "GROUP".

```
   GROUP  VAR_1            GROUP_MEAN
0      1      1  Mean Value GROUP = 1
1      1      1  Mean Value GROUP = 1
2      1      1  Mean Value GROUP = 1
3      2      3  Mean Value GROUP = 2
4      2      3  Mean Value GROUP = 2
```

I can easily access the overall mean:

```
df2['GROUP_MEAN'] = df2['VAR_1'].mean()
```

How do I go about making this conditional on a another column value?

Comment: `grouby`?  `df2.groupby('GROUP').mean()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a perfect use case for `transform`:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'VAR_1' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'GROUP': [1,1,1,2,2]})
>>> df2["GROUP_MEAN"] = df2.groupby('GROUP')['VAR_1'].transform('mean')
>>> df2
   GROUP  VAR_1  GROUP_MEAN
0      1      1         2.0
1      1      2         2.0
2      1      3         2.0
3      2      4         4.5
4      2      5         4.5

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Typically you use `transform` when you want to broadcast the result across all entries of the group.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that the actual data-frame has columns in addition to `VAR_1`

```
ts = df2.groupby( 'GROUP' )['VAR_1'].aggregate( np.mean )
df2[ 'GROUP_MEAN' ] = ts[ df2.GROUP ].values
```

alternatively last line could also be:

```
df2 = df2.join( ts, on='GROUP', rsuffix='_MEAN' )
```